# Difference between LocalCacheFolder and TemporaryFolder

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I wonder what's the difference between the [LocalCacheFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localcachefolder.aspx) and the [TemporaryFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.temporaryfolder.aspx).

Regarding MSDN, the LocalCacheFolder is not backed up/restored, but the temp folder isn't either, is it? What's the difference, then? Will only the temporary folder be deleted when I clean up storage manually`?

MSDN doesn't tell me a lot, so I hope someone can tell me the difference. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are folders that aren't backup up. The difference between them is that the OS may delete files from `TemporaryFolder` whenever it needs additional space. With `LocalCacheFolder`, you're responsible for deleting the files you don't need anymore.

You can find a more thorough explanation here: http://java.dzone.com/articles/windows-phone-81